# Python 3 - Misunderstanding of array syntax for comparison, simple question

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, syntax, boolean, comparison

I'm doing some exercises on CodingBat:

```
Given an array of ints, return True if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere.


array123([1, 1, 2, 3, 1]) → True
array123([1, 1, 2, 4, 1]) → False
array123([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]) → True
```

```
nums = [1,3,1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(nums)-2):

  if nums[i:i+2] == [1,2,3]:

    print("True")

print("False")
```

Why does nums[i:i+2] not equal nums[1,3,1], then I compare it with the desired array sequence...

This works, but I want to condense my code:

```
  for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
      print("True")
  print("False")
```

Comment: Try doing `print(nums[i:i+2])` in the loop. That will make this clearer.

Comment: OMG, I'm sorry for this waste of time... didn't realize my array size was too short... Thanks!

Comment: The upper bound of slicing is exclusive, like it is with ranges.

Comment: That's pretty useful insight, I suppose the python manual would have explained that? I should reference that for next time right?

Comment: It mentions it briefly on [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) page (by using the word "excluded"). That's probably a good page to read over if you haven't already.